# how to write function for a specific document in firestore?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

below is the function, i have used from youtube .

```
     const functions = require("firebase-functions");
     const admin = require("firebase-admin");

     admin.initializeApp();

     exports.androidPushNotification = 
     functions.firestore.document('MyMoneyNotifications/{MyPercentageMoney}').onCreate(

     (snapshot, context)=>
      {
         admin.messaging().sendToTopic(
      "new_user_forums",
   {
     notification:{
         title:snapshot.data().title,
         body: snapshot.data().body
                   }
            });});
```

it is working fine.
but i want to check for below structure.

```
        Notifications(collection)
              ->UserId(document)
                 ->MyNotification(collection)
                              ->notify1
                              ->notify2
```

now, i want to check for a specific user if he had any new notifications. how to check for the collection "MyNotification" in firebase functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to listen to sub-collections then you can set the path to:

```
exports.androidPushNotification = 
     functions.firestore.document('Notifications/{userId}/MyNotification/{notificationId}')
```

You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#:%7E:text=Your%20trigger%20must%20always%20point%20to%20a%20document)

Comment: @LTR the `snapshot` variable contains data of that newly created document. You can access it by `snapshot.data()`.

Comment: i want to get a user token for the notification. after a notification document is created, i need to send notification to a particular user. how can i get data from a document?  my database : users(collection) -> userId(document) ->Token(field).          
       i have to get userid from snapshot data.                                                                 
          val userId= snapshot.data().userid; from this userid, i have to get token from the user document in users collection. and also i have to send notification using that particular token

Comment: @LTR you can do so by `db.collection('users').doc(snapshot.data().id).get()` and then reading token field from it.

Comment: If that doesn't work out, please post a new question with more details and also it'll be better than comments here.